# Как добавить формулу в ячейку

Tags: google-apps-script

Прошу прощения за банальный вопрос, поискав в интернете нашёл решение:

```
sheet.getRange(lastRow, 9).setFormula("SUM(A1:A17)");
```

работает супер,

однако когда вставляю необходимую мне формулу:

```
sheet.getRange(lastRow, 9).setFormula("ВПР(D"+lastRow+";'Лист 2'!A:D;3;ЛОЖЬ)");
```

выдаёт "синтаксическая ошибка в формуле" Подскажите пожалуйста что не так с моей формулой? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо ЛОЖЬ поставить FALSE

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Вставил функцию на английском: sheet.getRange(lastRow, 9).setFormula("VLOOKUP(D"+lastRow+";'Коды счётчиков'!A:D;3;FALSE)");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удобнее использовать

```
sheet.getRange(lastRow, 9)
  .setValue("=VLOOKUP(D"+lastRow+";'Коды счётчиков'!A:D;3;FALSE)");
```

со знаком равно `=`. Дело в том, что `setFormula` немного для другого. Вставка алиасов на другие языки от версии к версии может не работать с этим методом.

Интересно, что

```
function updateValue() {
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(
    {
      values: [["=ВПР(D1;'Лист 2'!A:D;3;ЛОЖЬ)"]],
    },
    'ABCD1234',
    'Sheet3!I1',
    { valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED' }
  );
}
```

вставляет формулу как надо с использованием любых алиасов.

Comment: Спасибо, так действительно проще.

Answer (score 0):

Вставил функцию на английском:

```
sheet.getRange(lastRow, 9)
    .setFormula("VLOOKUP(D"+lastRow+";'Коды счётчиков'!A:D;3;FALSE)");
```